# Split the number on a decimal

Tags: java, string, split

How to delete all the character/ number after the . in a string

`String i = "154.232";`

I just want `154`

Thanks

My Code:

```
distance = crntLocation.distanceTo(newLocation)/1000; // in km
double newKB = Math.floor(distance);
String product_distance = String.valueOf(newKB);    
product_distance.replaceAll("\\..*", "");
```

Comment: use `Math.floor` to round the value.

Comment: Why not use int instead of double? `newKB = (int) distance;`
Includes floor function implicitely.

Comment: @Mr T, If your `String` contains only numbers then you don't need to use methods like `split()` , you can parse it to `Double` and use `Math.floor()` on the resultant value. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "154.232";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\..*", "");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

or

```
str.substring(0, str.indexOf("."));
```

or
// check for index of `.` is not `-1`, then do following.

```
str.split(".")[0];
```

**output**

```
154
```

Answer (score 2):

```
i=i.split(".")[0];
```

The .split function will return an array of strings on either side of the dot.
You want the part before the ., so take the first string in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Integer.parse()
```

or

```
Integer.decode()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
int id = str.indexOf(".");
if (id >= 0) str = str.substring(0, id);
```

to kill all characters after and including the first dot, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

first use `Double.parseDouble(String)` to parse it to a `Double` value, then use `Math.floor` to round it down,

```
String yourString = "154.9418";
// cast it to (int), since Math.floor returns a double
int toInt = (int) Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(yourString));
```

**output:**

```
154
```

**OR**

you could use `StringTokenizer` to split the string,

```
String yourString = "154.964687";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(yourString,".");
System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```

**output:**

```
154
```